# predict() function produces different values than hand calculation in a glmer

Tags: r, nested, logistic-regression, predict, glmm

I'm trying to obtain predicted probability of the source of my data (coded as 0 or 1, for source A and source B) from a glmer model.
Using example data:

```r
set.seed(123)
n<-7052
Df <- data.frame(
  source = sample(c(0, 1), n, replace = TRUE, 
      prob = c(0.719, 0.221)),  
  Response.number = sample(1:20, n, replace = TRUE),  
  Item.number = sample(1:40, n, replace = TRUE), 
  Ps.number = sample(1:40, n, replace = TRUE)  
)


Model1 <- glmer(source ~  (1|Response.number/Item.number) +
    (1|Ps.number), 
     data=Df,  family = binomial, 
       glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
```

As per https://sebastiansauer.github.io/convert_logit2prob/, the hand calculation `(exp(b)/(1+(exp(b))` produces the predicted probability the same as the function below:

```r
probability <- predict(Model1, type="response")
mean(probability)
```

I tried it with multiple types of practice data and this generally works (in the above example, it's 0.23199). However, when I use my actual data, I'm getting a slightly different value from the predict function (0.59) than by hand (0.57). I know it's not a lot but this discrepancy doesn't occur when I use any other data.

```r
head(Df_real)
      source    Response.number  Item.number  Ps.number
           0               1         1         1
           0               2         1         1
           1               3         1         1
           1               4         1         1
           0               5         1         1
           0               6         1         1
           0               1         2         1
           0               2         2         1
           1               3         2         1
           1               4         2         1
           0               5         2         1
           0               6         2         1
           0               1         1         2
           0               2         1         2
           1               3         1         2
           1               4         1         2
           0               5         1         2
           0               6         1         2
           0               1         2         2
           0               2         2         2
           1               3         2         2
           1               4         2         2
           0               5         2         2
```

etc.

The data is nested, that is, there is roughly the same amount of participants per each value of response, the same amount of responses per each value of item, etc. Can this be the source of the discrepancy? If so, how to deal with it? Is the `predict()` function appropriate?

Comment: We probably need to see your whole data set, or at least a subset that will allow us to repeat some computation exactly. `plogis(x)` does the same thing as `exp(x)/(1+exp(x))` and is likely to be slightly more reliable in cases of extremely large or small `x`.

Comment: You haven't really shown us what you are doing "by hand".  What `x` value are you using? How are you getting a single number from `predict` ?

Comment: @BenBolker I presumed the OP was using `b` as the intercept of the model (there are no fixed effect variables in the formula)

Comment: sorry, it's a mean of predicted values, corrected now. x in the formula you wrote is the intercept of the model, that's right

Answer (score 3):

When you run `predict` in `glmer`, it uses the variables present in your original data (including random effects) to estimate the probability, so you `predict` will not return a vector of values that are all the same as the single value you get by running `exp(b)/(1 + exp(b))` on the fixed effect coefficient.

To see this, let's try passing a little data frame of the random effect variables to the `newdata` argument of `predict`:

```r
predict(Model1, newdata = data.frame(Item.number = 1, 
                                     Response.number = c(1, 2), 
                                     Ps.number = 1), type = 'response')  
#>         1         2 
#> 0.2261900 0.2405297
```

Since you don't have any fixed effects in your model, the overall probability (accounting for the random effects) would simply be:

```r
b <- fixef(Model1)
exp(b)/(1 + exp(b))
#> (Intercept) 
#>   0.2319048
```

As Ben Bolker points out in the comments, this is not the same as the raw proportion in the data due to the bias adjustment used in glmms. He also points out that we can remove the random effects from `predict` using `re.form = NA`, which *will* give you the same value as the transformed intercept:

```r
mean(predict(Model1, type= 'response', re.form = NA)) == plogis(fixef(Model1))
#> (Intercept)
#>        TRUE
```

So it really depends on what you want to predict, i.e. whether you want the random variables taken into account or not. If you do, you can use `predict`, otherwise you can hand calculate from the fixed effects or use `re.form = NA` inside `predict`

As a side note, the base R function `plogis` is probably the easiest way to convert log odds to probability, and it clearly works here - we can see that using `type = "response"` is equivalent to `plogis(predict(Model1, type = "link"))`

```r
all(
  plogis(predict(Model1, type = "link")) == predict(Model1, type = "response")
)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Calculating it by hand is fine, though you will get very small floating point differences:

```r
b <- predict(Model1, type = "link")

hist(exp(b)/(1 + exp(b)) - predict(Model1, type = 'response'))
```

[image]

So the smart way to hand calculate the overall probability from your model is

```r
plogis(fixef(Model1))
#> (Intercept) 
#>   0.2319048
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but there is a very important distinction to make. If we run a GLM (no random effect), the mean of the data will be the same as the back-transformed intercept: `set.seed(101); x <- rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = 0.2); g <- glm(x ~ 1, family = binomial); all.equal(unname(plogis(coef(g))), mean(x))`. However, this is **not true** for GLMMs;  e.g. see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transformations.html#bias-adj

Comment: Also, if you want random effects ignored, you can use `predict(model, re.form = NA)`

Comment: @BenBolker I think then that this is essentially the answer that the OP was looking for. `mean(predict(Model1, type= 'response', re.form = NA))` is the same as `plogis(fixef(Model1))`

Comment: Thanks! The "re.form = NA" part is what makes the difference between R and my hand calculations - but I don't think I want random effects ignored, they are the only effects I have in the model. So is it ok to use the value from R even though it doesn't match hand calculation and attribute the difference to random effects?

Comment: @Agata what difference though? The mean of the probability output given by `predict`?

Comment: yes, with this part of the code it's 0.57, like the hand calculation, without it (just "mean(predict(Model1, type= 'response'))) it's 0.59

Comment: @Agata reporting (and having to defend) the mean of the output of `predict` isn't something I've ever come across or been asked about. Remember that the actual predictions are on the logistic scale and that when we use `type = 'response'` we are just transforming them. In general, `plogis(mean(predict(model)))` is not the same as `mean(plogis(predict(model)))`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an important point that you might be missing when comparing the means of the data with the means of the predictions. @AllanCameron's comment that `plogis(mean(predict(model)))` is not the same as `mean(plogis(predict(model)))` (this is *Jensen's inequality*).

```r
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)
set.seed(123)
n <- 7052
Df <- data.frame(
  Response.number = sample(1:20, n, replace = TRUE),  
  Item.number = sample(1:40, n, replace = TRUE), 
  Ps.number = sample(1:40, n, replace = TRUE)  
)
Df$source <- simulate(~(1|Response.number/Item.number) +  (1|Ps.number),
   family = binomial,
   newdata = Df,
   newparams = list(beta = qlogis(0.7), theta = c(1, 1, 1)))[[1]]
fit <- glmer(source ~(1|Response.number/Item.number) +  (1|Ps.number),
   family = binomial,
   data = Df)
```

```r
mean(Df$source)  ## 0.6498866
(p1 <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(dummy = 1), re.form = NA)) ## 0.9280772
plogis(p1)  ## 0.716685
(p2 <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(dummy = 1), 
    re.form = NA, type = "response")) ## 0.716685
emmeans(fit, ~ 1)
emmeans(fit, ~ 1)
##  1       emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
##  overall  0.928 0.263 Inf     0.412      1.44
emmeans(fit, ~ 1, type = "response")
## 1        prob     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
##  overall 0.717 0.0535 Inf     0.602     0.809
```

From [emmeans vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transformations.html#bias-adj)

```r
vars <- sapply(VarCorr(fit), c)
total.SD <- sqrt(sum(vars^2))
emmeans(fit, ~ 1, type = "response", bias.adj = TRUE,
  sigma = total.SD)
##  1        prob     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
##  overall 0.614 0.0398 Inf     0.545     0.698
```

The bias correction isn't exact (it uses a *delta method* approximation) so that's not quite right, but it's closer.

This is a little better:

```r
library(logitnorm)
momentsLogitnorm(mu = fixef(fit), sigma = total.SD)
##       mean        var 
## 0.65790176 0.06472473
```

Or:

```r
mean(predict(fit, type = "response")) ## 0.6500409
```